Initialise the date in a date type field
Why does 'jj - mm - aaaa' appear in the 'From' input field instead of the date of the last Sunday (see line 50 in included source) after selecting ‘Voting period’ in the drop-down menu ?
However, this field displays correctly '9999' or the (today's) desired date after selecting 'Question nr' resp. 'Creation date' in this drop-down menu, as well as the number '1' or the correct dates in the 'To' field !?
Why is the ‘formattedLastSunday’ constant not accepted as From.value on line 50 (Javascript) ?

<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php
    if (!isset($_GET["select"]) OR $_GET["select"] == "") $select = "1"; else $select = $_GET["select"];        //  echo "===".$select."===";
    if (!isset($_GET["From"  ]) OR $_GET["From"  ] == "") {if ($select == "1") $From = "9999"; else $From = "2024-01-01" ;} else $From = $_GET["From"];     //  echo "===".$From."===";
    if (!isset($_GET["To"    ]) OR $_GET["To"    ] == "") {if ($select == "1") $To   = "1"   ; else $To   = "2024-01-01" ;} else $To   = $_GET["To"  ];     //  echo "===".$To."===";
    echo "[ Sent by form to the server (php) : ===".$select."===".$From."===".$To."=== ]";
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
        <title>Test_03</title>
        <script>
            function btnInset(p1) {
            //  alert("--"+p1+"--"+p2+"--"+p3+"--");
                var btn = document.getElementById('btn'+p1)
                btn.classList.replace("btnOutset", "btnInset");
            //  document.forms[0].elements['btn_'].value = p1;
            }

            function chgSelect(p) {
            //  alert ('Change to option '+p+' !');
                
                var From = document.getElementById('From');
                if (p == 1) {
                    From.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                    From.setAttribute('size', '4');
                    From.value = 9999;
                } else if (p == 2) {
                    From.setAttribute('type', 'date');
                    From.setAttribute('size', '8');
                    var today = new Date();
                    From.valueAsDate = today;
                } else {        // (p = 3)
                    From.setAttribute('type', 'date');
                    From.setAttribute('size', '8');
                    var now = new Date();
                    var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
                    var lastSunday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - today.getDay()));
                    const yyyy = lastSunday.getFullYear();
                    let mm = lastSunday.getMonth() + 1;     // Months start at 0!
                    let dd = lastSunday.getDate();
                    if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;
                    if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;
            //      const formattedLastSunday = '"' + yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + '"';
                    const formattedLastSunday = '"' + dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy + '"';
            //      alert(formattedLastSunday);             // OK !
                    From.value = formattedLastSunday;       // KO ! Why ?
            //      From.value = '"' + yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd + '"';
                }
                
                var To = document.getElementById('To');
                if (p == 1) {
                    To.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                    To.setAttribute('size', '4');
                    To.value = 1;
                } else if (p == 2) {
                    To.setAttribute('type', 'date');
                    To.setAttribute('size', '8');
                    To.value = "2024-01-02";
                } else {        // (p = 3)
                    To.setAttribute('type', 'date');
                    To.setAttribute('size', '8');
                    To.value = "2024-01-04";
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body style="text-align: center;">
        <h1> &nbsp; </h1>
        <form action="">
            <label for="select"> Select and sort by </label>
            <select name="select" id="select" onChange="chgSelect(value);">
                <option value="1" <?php if($select == 1) echo "selected" ?>> Question nr </option>
                <option value="2" <?php if($select == 2) echo "selected" ?>> Creation date </option>
                <option value="3" <?php if($select == 3) echo "selected" ?>> Voting period </option>
            </select> &nbsp;
            <label for="From"> : &nbsp; From </label>
            <input name="From" id="From" type="<?php if($select == 1) echo "text"; else echo "date"; ?>" style="text-align: center;" size="4" value="<?php echo $From ?>"/> &nbsp;
            <label for="To"> To </label>
            <input name="To" id="To" type="<?php if($select == 1) echo "text"; else echo "date"; ?>" style="text-align: center;" size="4" value="<?php echo $To ?>"/> &nbsp;
            <button id="btn1" type="submit" class="btnOutset" onclick="btnInset(1);"> Submit </button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


Since this is a javascript (client-side) error, please [edit] your question to show the rendered html, rather than your php.

And which line is line 50?  What debugging you have done in the JavaScript in your browser?  Can you provide a [mcve] which can be independently tested to demonstrate the problem?

FYI you can simplify !isset($_GET["XXX"]) OR $_GET["XXX"] == "" to just empty($_GET['select'])

Why are you adding extra quotation marks to the date string? dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy should suffice (although, in my experience, date inputs require yyyy-mm-dd format).

The value of a date input must be in the standard format yyyy-MM-dd:

<input type="date"> - MDN
The date is formatted according to Date strings format.

You are trying to set it to a value in the format dd-MM-yyyy, which is invalid. This is effectively the same as clearing the input.
NB: You can simplify the date formatting code:
const now = new Date();
const today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
const lastSunday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - today.getDay()));

const formattedLastSunday = lastSunday.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
From.value = formattedLastSunday;


Thanks to you, Mykaf and Richard, "From.value = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;" is the right answer. It works perfectly now. Thanks also for your advices, Barmar and David. JoVD.
